# Once again, how do I convert ct100 IDs to original id using javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a tag element in .aspx page:

```
 <a id="loginLink" runat="server" class="loginLink" href="#" onclick="$('registerform').hide(); $('signin').show(); this.style.display='none';   $('back').show(); $('reg-signin-email').focus(); return false">Already signed up? Log in here</a>
```

and trying to get loginLink.ClientID , but it spits back ct100_main_loginLink. How do I get original 'loginLink' id in the same aspx page?

Tried var ctrl = document.getElementById('<%# loginLink.ClientID %>');
and it didnt work..

example:

```
<asp:Content runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="Main">

        <a id="loginLink" runat="server" class="loginLink" href="#" onclick="$('registerform').hide(); $('signin').show(); this.style.display='none';   $('back').show(); $('reg-signin-email').focus(); return false">Already signed up? Log in here</a>

        <script type="text/javascript">   alert('diplay here original loginLink ID instead of ct100_Main_LoginLink');  </script>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Can you post the code where you tried what you say you tried?  Did you do that in a `<script>` block in the `<head>`?

Comment: I think you have a major mixup about what happens on the server and what happens on the client. Maybe you should tell what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: For that 2nd part, when you view your source, assuming you see "ct100_main_loginLink" as the id of the hyperlink, what are you seeing for the "var ctrl = ..."?

Comment: @Tomalak I am trying to get original id instead of ct100... so I could use it in the same page.

Comment: show the JS that you are talking about wanting to 'use it in the same page'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you know the name, and that's what you want to have available in js,  you can just type it in js. alternatively, if you want the control to provide its own id, you could do

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
  alert('<% =loginLink.ID %>');  
</script>
```

although I don't see the point in that. if you need to grab the element during a javascript routine, you'll need the `ClientID` value as there won't be any element on the page with the short-form id in the example I've given.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write `'<%# loginLink.ClientID %>'`, and you can only write it in the original ASPX page.  (Not an external JS file)

If you wnat to get the original ID (which never shows up on the client), use `loginLink.ID`.

Answer (score 0):

if you use a tool like FireBug you will see that the actual ID output to the client is the long one with ct100.... in ASP.NET pages.

You will not normally get loginlink back to the client unless you are using Dot.NET 4.0 and controlling the client-mode.

in your example the var ctrl should hold a reference to the DOM element